# Check Oozie status in UNIX

Tags: bash, hadoop

**Hadoop Admin Utility**

Created a basic hadoop admin utility which checks dfs health and oozie  status.

**Checking oozie status**

In my above utility, I am using the below command :

```
bin/oozie admin -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -status
```

**Concern of the above command**

When oozie is not working correctly, this call will not return in less than an hour or 2. The utility will be on Hung state for long time. This might impact the UNIX box.

**Alternate Solution**

We can check the oozie logs

```
tail -100 oozie.log
```

- Compare the latest timestamp of the log with system date(timestamp) . If the **oozie_timestamp < 5 min(Any Threshold limit) of system_timestamp** , then print message as "**Oozie has stopped running**".
- Check/Grep the word "Error" in Oozie log.

Is there any other alternative solution to get oozie status other "**Oozie status command**" and  "**Parsing of Oozie log files**"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the web service url directly with curl and manually set the timeout on the request:

```
curl -m 10 http://localhost:11000/oozie/v1/admin/status
```

The `-m` switch is the total time you'll wait for a response before failing.

There also might be an option to amend the default timeout of the http client oozie uses (maybe via a system property set via `-Dkey=value`), but you'll need to dig down into the source and see if that's possible